# How to conditionally change visibility with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change a `div`'s visibility from hidden to visible using button click. But even when I am clicking the button, the visibility is not changing. I have logged the console after the clickHandler, and it still says false even after I set it to true inside the function. So far, I have this,

```
let clicked = false;
  //change image on fortune cookie click
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    e.target.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://i.ibb.co/cksx7kr/kisspng-fortune-cookie-drawing-clip-art-fortune-cookie-5b237469209879-9079770415290502171335.png"
    );
    
    clicked = true;
  };
  console.log(clicked);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>
        <img
          className="cookie"
          src="https://i.ibb.co/9YQV2qq/kisspng-fortune-cookie-biscuits-bakery-drawing-clip-art-fortune-cookies-5b0ec5e3013c23-3980054715276.png"
        />
      </button>
      <div
        className="fortuneMessage"
        style={{ visibility: clicked ? "visible" : "hidden" }}
      >
        {fortune}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: this is not how you deal with state changes in React - simply changing an internal variable in the function will not cause a rerender. Look into `useState` (and React state in general)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using React, you need a state in order to have a DOM update. That would fork for you (don't forget to import `useState` at the top of your file) :

```js
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [src, setSrc] = useState("https://i.ibb.co/9YQV2qq/kisspng-fortune-cookie-biscuits-bakery-drawing-clip-art-fortune-cookies-5b0ec5e3013c23-3980054715276.png");
  
  //change image on fortune cookie click
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    setSrc("https://i.ibb.co/cksx7kr/kisspng-fortune-cookie-drawing-clip-art-fortune-cookie-5b237469209879-9079770415290502171335.png");
    setClicked(true);
  };
  console.log(clicked);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>
        <img
          className="cookie"
          src={src}
        />
      </button>
      <div
        className="fortuneMessage"
        style={{ visibility: clicked ? "visible" : "hidden" }}
      >
        {fortune}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use state instead of the plain `clicked` variable.

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
```

Call the `setState` function inside the `clickHandler` function instead of setting `clicked` to `true`.

```
setClicked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

in React, the variable is not two way binding.

The clicked variable in your function will only get to be `true` in the function itself but not outside the function

So in this case you need to use `useState` so that the clicked state will be re-rendered again with updated boolean

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
const clickHandler = () => {
    setClicked(true)
}
```

so that your clicked variable will be updated, hence the css will be updated again.

for more reference with `useState` can check their documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html